# Access data efficiently in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Would like to know is it possible to have a better way to get the data from the database easily via eloquent? The following is the code i use usually, and thinking of get all records match to the shopID but it would be inefficient in filter and access in the loop.

```
$add1 = ShopMeta::where('shopId', '=', $theID)->where('metadataKey', '=', 1015)->firstOrFail();
```

The benefit of this is i can access the member with the following instead of foreach loop.

```
$add1->metadataValue;
```

Is there any better methods to do the job of get all the value?

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, but you want this for multiple `shopId`s?

Comment: @Raphael_, i'm sorry for confuse you. i want this for multiple metadataKey. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [Scoped Query](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) is for.

Comment: Thanks @HanLuo, but with this method is there any possible easier access to the data? Cause i have about 20 of metadataKey in a single controller. Thanks

Comment: Yes with Dynamic scopes, you can specify your metadataKey in the scope so it would look like ShopMeta::meta($id, $key)->firstOrFail();  In the scope function, you have to to the querybuilder variable as the first parameter.  Refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `whereIn`:

```
$add1 = ShopMeta::where('shopId', '=', $theID)
                ->whereIn('metadataKey', array(1015, 1016))
                ->get();
```

Comment: @Raphel_, May i know how can i access the member later on? Important is that part :) Thx

Comment: Well, if you use `get`, this means you'll getting multiple records, which means you'll need a foreach loop. If you use `first` (as in your example), it's just as simple as `$add1->metadataKey`. I'm not sure though, from your question, if you want multiple records or a single one.

Comment: I want to access the data in single line. Let say if getting data via get(), how could i filter later on? Thx